# Different variance formulas, how to get from one to the other?

Tags: statistics, expectation, variance

I have the following formula for variance

(1) $Var(X) = E((X - \mu)^2)$

(2) $Var(X) = E(X^2) - E(X)^2$ (2)

(3) $Var(X) = \sum(x_i-\mu_x)^2p_i$

I know how to get from (1) to (2), but if I'm given $n$ numbers and told to compute the variance of them, I can't use (1) or (2) but I think (3). The most I've proved to myself is that $E(X)$ for a uniform distribution is the same as the "mean" or "average".

Comment: If $X$ is a discrete r.v., $E(X) = \sum_i x_i p_i$. Make sure you know this, and the rest should fall in place.

Comment: @mlc got it, thanks!

Comment: Why couldn't you use (1) and (2) for $n$ numbers? $E((X-\mu)^2)$ simply means that you first calculate their expected value $\mu$ (i.e. "average"), then subtract it from each number, square it and you have a new collection of $n$ numbers. All you have to do is calculate the expected value of those new numbers, using the original probabilities.

Answer (score 0):

The first two formulas are the definition of variance
$$
Var(X) = E(X - EX)^2 = EX^2 - E^2X.
$$
Now, if $X$ is continuous random variable then 
$$
Var(X) = \int (x-\mu_X)^2f_X(x)dx,
$$
if $X$ is discrete, then 
$$
Var(X) = \sum_{x  } (x-\mu_x)^2P(X=x).
$$

If you have $n$ numbers $x_1,...,x_n$, i.e., $n$ realization of some random variable $X$ then its sample variance can be computed by 
$$
S^2 = \frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar{x}_n)^2.
$$